# Probability of ace

Tags: probability

From a deck of $32$ cards randomly one is being extracted (and not being returned) until it is an ace. For the first time ace appeared after $10$th extraction. What is the probability that the next card is the ace of spades?

---

The very naive approach gives the probability $\frac{1}{22}$ since there are $22$ cards left and one of them is an ace of spades. This doesn't feel right though. What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure the deck has just $32$ cards? Feels it should be $52$..

Comment: You need to condition on the first ace not being spades.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming the deck is composed of four aces and $28$ non-aces.

We deal out all $32$ cards, so there are $32!$ possible orderings of the deck, all of which we assume are equally likely.  Let's say $A$ is the event that the first ace is card number $10$ and $B$ is the event that the ace of spades is card number $11$, so what we want to find is the conditional probability
$$P(B|A) = \frac{P(AB)}{P(A)} \tag{1}$$
For $P(AB)$, we want to count the number of arrangements in which the first ace is card number $10$ and the ace of spades is card number $11$. We have $9$ non-aces, followed by an ace other than the aces of spades, followed by the ace of spades, followed by the remaining $21$ cards.  There are $\binom{28}{9}$ ways to pick the first $9$ cards, which can be ordered in $9!$ ways, then $3$ choices of the first ace, then only one choice for the ace of spades, and then $21!$ ways to order the remaining cards.  So
$$P(AB) = \frac{\binom{28}{9} 9! \times 3 \times 1 \times 21!}{32!} \tag{2}$$

For $P(A)$, we want to count the number of arrangements in which the first ace is card number $10$.   We have $9$ non-aces, followed by an ace, followed by the remaining $22$ cards.  As before, the first $9$ cards can be chosen in $\binom{28}{9}$ ways and then ordered in $9!$ ways.  The ace can be chosen in $4$ ways, and then the remaining $22$ cards can be ordered in $22!$ ways. So
$$P(A) = \frac{\binom{28}{9} 9! \times 4 \times 22!}{32!} \tag{3}$$
Substituting $(2)$ and $(3)$ into equation $(1)$ and simplifying, we find
$$P(B|A) = \frac{3}{88}$$